# Mysqli, stuck between "or die" and "sqlierror"

Tags: php, mysqli, dreamweaver, wampserver

I'm having a trouble around starting a session. Here's my php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pttkhdt');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    else {
        $a = $_SESSION['a'];
        $knad ='SELECT * FROM admintb WHERE adID=' .$a;
        $naad = mysqli_query($con,$knad);
        $arad = array();
        while($rowad=mysqli_fetch_assoc($naad)) $arad[] = $rowad;
    }
?>
```

If I input that, when I tried to test run my site, it will show:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...
```

But if I fix the line

```
$naad=mysqli_query($con,$knad);
```

Into:

```
$naad=mysqli_query($con,$knad) or die;
```

the page will "die" out and blank.

Comment: just make sure that `$a` has its value. and why not use prepared statements, mysqli supports this anyways

Comment: Um, can you be more specific, please? I already add a row into admintb, or did you mean something else by "make sure `$a` has its value?

Comment: thats already straightforward as it gets really. just make sure that `$a` has a value. it'll screw up the query once its empty. to check just use `var_dump($a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you're loading your mysqli_fetch_assoc into an array, using a while loop. However, a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is already loading an array.

Why don't you try this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pttkhdt');
  if ( mysqli_errno($con) ) {
    //Exit stops the rest of the script
    exit( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($con) );
  } else {
    $a = $_SESSION['a'];
    $knad = "SELECT * FROM admintb WHERE adID='" . $a . "'";
    $arad = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($con,$knad) );
    if (!$arad) { exit( mysqli_error($con) ); }
  }
?>
```

The reason behind your sql error may be the fact that your prior SQL $knad statements says for example, `adID=justatestvalue`, so your SQL is searching for the column justatestvalue. Make sure to enclose actual statements in quotes.

`mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName='$user'");`

Answer (score 0):

Check your error with mysql_error() and update your error here;

```
$naad=mysqli_query($con,$knad) or die(mysql_error());
```

or try this code below

```
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd);
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$link);
if(!$db) die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my wampserver won't let my use mysql, I have to use mysqli instead, or else it will show "DEPRECATED ERROR"